# How change/drop foreign key on MySql table and associate to another table?

Tags: mysql

*tbl_table1* have columns *'Id'*, *'Type_Id'* and 'Name'.
*'Type_Id'* is Foreign_Key that reference to *tbl_table2* *'Type_Id'*

I have make a copy of *tbl_table2* and renamed it to *tbl_glob_table2* with same values and columns.

**My problem:**
How can i change the Foreign_Key reference from **tbl_table2.Type_Id** to **tbl_glob_table2.Type_Id**

**Error message when i will update tbl_table1:**
"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails.

**ALTER TABLE tbl_table1 DROP FOREIGN KEY Type_Id**

give me following error message:
*#1091 - Can't DROP 'Type_Id'; check that column/key exists*

**Create Table statement:**

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_table1
    CREATE TABLE `tbl_table1` (
     `Id` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
     `Type_Id` int(3) NOT NULL,
     `Name` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 'noname',
     PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
     KEY `FK_tbl_table1_type` (`Type_Id`),
     CONSTRAINT `tbl_table1_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`Type_Id`) REFERENCES `tbl_table2` (`Type_Id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

Comment: Show us the create table statement for the table please.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `tbl_table1` (
 `Id` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `Type_Id` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `Name` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 'noname',
 PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
 KEY `FK_tbl_table1_type` (`Type_Id`),
 CONSTRAINT `tbl_table1_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`Type_Id`) REFERENCES `tbl_table2` (`Type_Id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the symbol name (name of the constraint) to drop a foreign key, not the name of the index. In this case: tbl_table1_ibfk_2.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_table1 DROP FOREIGN KEY tbl_table1_ibfk_2
```

Comment: SQL query:


`ALTER TABLE tbl_table1_ibfk_2 DROP FOREIGN KEY Type_Id`
**MySQL said: Documentation**

`#1146 - Table 'database.tbl_table1_ibfk_2' doesn't exist`

Comment: I wrote that use the symbol name instead of the index name. Not instead of the table name.

Comment: Ok, thak you :)
your answer is accepted as correct answer.